# How to close one modal and open another with Chakra UI?

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I have a modal form which I'd like to be on multiple modals. Basically, in the first modal, the user is asked some information. Then, after pressing the button 'Next', the first modal closes and the second one opens asking other information. I figure the 'onClose' for the button 'Next' should close the first modal and then open the next. However, I can't seem to make it work.
I have

```
const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure()
const { isOpenSecond, onOpenSecond, onCloseSecond } = useDisclosure()
```

then

```html
<button onClick="{onOpen}">SIGN UP</button>
<Modal closeOnOverlayClick="{false}" isOpen="{isOpen}" onClose="{onClose}">
  <ModalOverlay />
  <ModalContent>
    <ModalHeader>Create an account</ModalHeader>
    <ModalCloseButton />
    <ModalBody>
      <Stack spacing="25px">
        //first part of the form
      </Stack>
    </ModalBody>
    <ModalFooter>
      <button colorScheme="blue" mr="{3}" onClick="{" onClose }>
        NEXT &#8594;
      </button>
    </ModalFooter>
  </ModalContent>
</Modal>
<Modal
  closeOnOverlayClick="{false}"
  isOpen="{isOpenSecond}"
  onClose="{onClose}"
>
  <ModalOverlay />
  <ModalContent>
    <ModalHeader>Test</ModalHeader>
    <ModalCloseButton />
    <ModalBody>
      <Stack spacing="25px">
        //second part of the form here
      </Stack>
    </ModalBody>
    <ModalFooter>
      <button colorScheme="blue" mr="{3}" onClick="{onClose}">
        NEXT &#8594;
      </button>
    </ModalFooter>
  </ModalContent>
</Modal>
```

How can I make onClose close one modal and open another? And another onClose closes altogether the form.

Answer (score 0):

you typo on this

```
<button colorScheme="blue" mr="{3}" onClick="{" onClose }>
```

and i think you need handler like this

```
const handleModal = () => {
Onclose,
OnOpenSecond
}
```

and in view you can add like this

```
<button colorScheme="blue" mr="{3}" onClick="{() => handleModal()}">
```

i never use chakra ui, sorry if the code wrong, but that is the logic i think

Answer (score 0):

I had this usecase too, so I was able to implement it after some hours staring at PC

you can basically just use conditional statement in the function that would be called in your onClick event. for Example:

```
   const openSignUpModal = () => {
    onSignUpOpen()
    if (isLoginOpen) {
      onLoginClose()
    }
  }
```

where we have `const { isOpen: isLoginOpen, onOpen: onLoginOpen, onClose: onLoginClose } = useDisclosure()` and `const { isOpen: isSignUpOpen, onOpen: onSignUpOpen, onClose: onSignUpClose } = useDisclosure()`

in this case login can be the first while signup can be the second, vice versa.